# With Internet Explorer being exempt from Security Updates, should we disable our Websites from working within this Browser?

Tags: security

As new problems arise security-wise, I am concerned about having to implement code that isn't as secure (leaving vulnerabilities) as what the modern browsers will provide.

Should we just not populate within Internet Explorer's browser at all?
Should we be willing to let Internet Explorer always be an option for those looking to exploit?

I hope this is a relevant/valid question for you, I think it's certainly a reasonable concern.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes ideally as any browser version is excluded out of support we should be rejecting connections being made out of such clients.

Comment: Thank you. As this would be quite a bit of work for some businesses, I would want to be sure that this is the best way to go about this - before asking Clients to take such steps as updating their machines.